# Ubuntu 12.04 disc mounting issues

Tags: 12.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 from 10.04.  My laptop has two hard disks and when I mount the second disk, I no longer have any control over the file permissions (even in su mode).  So none of the software I have installed on that disk works anymore.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you give more details, please? 1) How do you mount it? 2) What are the options in your /etc/fstab ? 3) Please give us the output when you run the 'mount' command

Comment: here is what is in my /etc/fstab file:

Comment: 1) I mount it by just clicking on the icon in a standard file folder (as I did in version 10.04)

Comment: 2) here is the /etc/fstab file :

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sdb4 during installation
UUID=c43e384a-0675-4b88-84b7-3eb8ecc1a575 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

Comment: # /boot was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=4b714b5a-2cfd-4752-b7bc-8059e16a31fd /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=e6c07b63-5621-4c2f-a8c1-4cb72ad36960 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: 3) when I type "mount /media/Data" there is no output.  It mounts, I just get no ability to control the permissions.  it is an ntsf drive

Comment: First, like shlomo said, you should use pastebin.com for uploading output and only put the link here. To 3): I meant the output if you just enter 'mount' without the device, but after you have mounted it the way you mount it. This gives you a list of all currently mounted devices and their options.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from what I read there you have /dev/sdb4 which is mounted as your root filesystem. You also have /dev/sda2 which is your swap. Otherwise there seem to be no partitions on your hard disk. Which is most likely part of the issue. Please open a terminal, type "sudo blkid" and post the output here. If you don't know how to use a terminal, use google.

Please also use pastebin.com if you want to paste code here. The idea is, that you go there, paste your code, get a link, get back here and paste the link. Keeps everything clean and readable.

Cheers

Comment: OK from what I gather the problem is with how 12.04 mounts an ntsf drive versus the way 10.04 did.  In 10.04 the drive mounted such that the permissions were made and defined like a native linux environment (i.e., folders got the rwx and files inherently got the rw permissions.. but the user was allowed to make files executable with the chmod command).  The new 12.04 does not mount in this way.  If I modify the /etc/fstab file to have the ntsf drive with the option "umask=000" the scripts and other software I have work, but this option makes *every* file executable, which is not desirable.

Comment: Is there a combination of umask=###,fmask=###,dmask=### that will make the drive behave like a standard linux environment?

Comment: :) well, since I've stopped using Windows about ten years ago, I have no experience whatsoever in this area. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah I never use windows either...  I have a windows partition (that is rarely used) that, at the time, required me to have my other drive be ntsf so that I could write to it.